# Python scope of int vs scope of list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having troubles understanding the scope concept in Python. When I use the following code:|

```
x = 100

def printer(x):
    x = 25
    print(x)

printer(x) -> prints 25
print(x) -> prints 100
```

In the example above I understand the variable 'x' only has 25 as value in the function. When I try to do the same with a list, my output is different. See code below:

```
board = ['','']

def printer():
    board[0] = 'X'
    print(board)

printer() --> prints ['X', '']
print(board) --> also prints ['X', ''] || Here I was expecting to print ['','']
```

Comment: This has **nothing** to do with scope. In one case, you are *re-assigning the variable `x`, in the other, your are *mutating the object referenced by the variable x*. Note, change `board = ['X', '']` in your second example and you'll see it works the same.

Comment: Read the following: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: Lists are working with referance so if you change it in a function then it will change on local

Comment: @ikibir `list` and `int` objects both *work exactly the same*, they *both* use reference semantics, `int` objects *merely lack mutator methods*.

Comment: It's somewhat about scope, as the change to `board = ['X', '']` changes `board` from a free variable to a local variable.

Comment: @chepner yes, good point.

Answer (score 5):

Only *names* have scopes. The `x` you assign before `printer` is a global name. The parameter `x` *in* `printer` is local to `printer`.

`board` is a global name. Since you never assign to `board` inside `printer` (`board[0] = 'X'` is *not* an assignment to `board`; it's a method call `board.__setattr__(0, 'X')`), it is a free variable whose value is taken from a name in an enclosing scope. The assignment mutates an existing value referenced by the global name `board`.